# google maps: How to create static images containing lots of GPS path points

Tags: google-maps, vba, excel

I need to create images of GPS paths on top of google maps satellite information.  The ultimate goal is to import those images in a report that is being created in an Excel program that is run through userforms & VBA.

I'm having trouble coming up with a way to automate the generation of these images.  Preferably the user would not have to install additional software and there would be a way of automating this process using VBA.  I would like to use the Static Google Maps API, but that is limited by the number of characters in an HTML request (2048 as I understand) and my path data is easily going to exceed that length.

Let's assume for now that I have a single KML file with my GPS path data.

Any thoughts on a way to convert large KML path files into static maps image files using VBA?  I'm imagining VBA opening a local HTML file with a dynamic google map, uploading the KML file, and somehow capturing and saving a screenshot of the KML data loaded onto the dynamic google map.

FYI I'm locked into using the existing Excel/VBA forms-based program to generate these reports.

(new to this board and relatively new at programming so please let me know if my description is lacking.  thanks)

Comment: The FAQ on the Google Maps API suggests using the Google Earth API instead for intranet applications like the one you are suggesting - see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#intranet_kml

Comment: @barrowc I don't think this is suitable for rendering images. 'Rendering' here refers to the program output of the data (be it Google Earth or the Maps API)

Comment: Would the Google Earth API require that the user has Google Earth installed?

Comment: To answer my own question... yes it seems like you need the plug-in installed.  I was trying to avoid that